# How to determine the convergence of this series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was wondering how to determine the convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{x=1}^{+\infty}  x!(\sin^x(\frac{x}{x^2+1}))$$
I tried to solve it on my own, using first comparison test and later root criterion but I have not solved it yet. Then, I put it on Wolfram Alpha, its output is just that the series converges for the comparison test. It is not possible to look at every steps with Wolfram Alpha Pro and other solvers as well. Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1,2,\dots,$ we have

$$0 <\sin \left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right) < \sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) < 1/n.$$

Thus the given series converges if $\sum \dfrac{n!}{n^n}$ converges. But note that for $n>1,$

$$\frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{n}{n} \frac{n-1}{n} \cdots \frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{2}{n^2}.$$

Since $\sum 2/n^2 <\infty,$ the given series converges

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we know that for $x \geq 0$, $\sin(x) \leq x$. Therefore:
$$
n!\sin^n\left(\frac{n}{n^2 + 1}\right) \leq n!\left(\frac{n}{n^2 + 1}\right)^n = \frac{n!n^n}{(n^2 + 1)^n} \leq \frac{n!n^n}{(n^2)^n} = \frac{n!}{n^n}
$$
Now apply ratio test on this term, and we see that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)!/(n+1)^{n+1}}{n!/n^n}  = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n} = \frac{1}{e} < 1
$$
Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges, and by comparison test so does the original series.

Answer (score 0):

It also works fine with the ratio test using composition of  Taylor series.

$$a_x=x!\Big[\sin\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)\Big]^x\implies \log(a_x)=\log(x!)+x \log\Big[\sin\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)\Big]$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{7}{6 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1} {x^5}\right)$$
$$\log\Big[\sin\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)\Big]=-\log \left({x}\right)-\frac{7}{6
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1} {x^4}\right)$$ Now, use Stirling approximation for $\log(x!)$ and you will get
$$\log(a_x)=-x+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({x}\right)\right)-\frac{13}{12 x}+O\left(\frac{1} {x^3}\right)$$ Apply it twice and continue with Taylor series to get
$$\log(a_{x+1})-\log(a_x)=-1+\frac{1}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1} {x^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{x+1} } {a_x }=e^{\log(a_{x+1})-\log(a_x) }=\frac 1 e \left(1+\frac{1}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1} {x^2}\right) \right)$$

Just for your curiosity, the partial sums converge very fast and after $14$ terms is reached the value of $1.06044$.